# Magento Connect Manager redirecting to 3rd party site - malicious code?

Tags: magento

I have a strange problem with Magento Connect Manager:  firstly, if I cliick the "settings" tab, the page redirects to an the 1and1.com.com homepage with an affiliate link suffix (1and1 arent my hosting provider).

Similarly, if I try and uninstall / reinstall any extension on the "extensions" page, the same  1and1.com page appears in the window below the list of extensions (where you would normally see the installation being actioned).

I am also unable to install any new extensions / or uninstall any existing ones.  I'm guessing this is the result of some malicious code being inserted somewhere?

does anyone else have any similar experience or any idea how to fix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback your updated htaccess to default magento htaccess and clear your cache and test again.

OR

In your current htaccess file you may find some urls like
http://www.yourdomain.com/
update them to your website url.